# Reading a partial file stream into a string using iterators

Tags: c++, string, iterator

This is what I have tried so far but with no success:

```
std::string ReadPartial( std::ifstream& _file, int _size )
{
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> first( _file );
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> last( _file );
    std::advance( last, _size );
    return std::string( first, last ); 
}
```

I know how to read the whole file.

```
std::string Read( std::ifstream& _file )
{
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> first( _file );
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> last();
    return std::string( first, last ); 
}
```

But this is not what i want to do. I'm getting an empty string.  If I look at first and last in a debugger they point to the same thing even after the std::advance.

Comment: What’s the actual result that you’re seeing? Also, please post the *real* code that you used. The above code doesn’t even compile (EDIT: before Charles fixed it …).

Comment: Ok fixed the compilation error.Sorry that was my bad.  Was typing out of my head.

Comment: No need to use HTML, markdown works great.

Comment: By habit, I changed ifstream to istream in my answer, but it should be explicitly mentioned: pass file streams as istreams or ostreams (or, very rarely, iostreams) if you don't need the file-specific methods (open, close, etc.).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is there some particular reason you want to use iterators? You could just read the bytes in one go:

```
std::string s(_size, '\0');
_file.read(&s[0], _size);
```

If you really want to read using iterators, you could do this:

```
std::string ReadPartial( std::ifstream& _file, int _size )
{
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> first( _file );
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> last;
    std::string s;
    s.reserve(_size);
    while (_size-- && first != last) s += *first++;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: No its not necessary.  But would like to know if it is possible. Thanks for the answer

Comment: `file.read(&s[0], size)` is non-portable and unsafe. basic_string doesn't have vector's contiguous-storage guarantee.

Comment: @Steve: For what implementation is that true?

Comment: @Roger: I'd rather just not know, because the standard allows implementors to change it whenever they want. Why have abstractions if we're going to be encouraged to write code that assumes a certain implementation?

Comment: @Steve: Contiguous storage is [required for string via indexing](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#530) (what's missing is an explicit guarantee for iterators).  0x guarantees contiguous storage in all ways for std::string.

Answer (score 6):

```
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> first( _file );
std::istreambuf_iterator<char> last( _file );
std::advance( last, _size );
```

istreambuf_iterators are Input Iterators.  Once you advance last, the *other iterator is modified too.*  You are treating them as Forward Iterators, which have the property that you can copy an iterator, advance it, then get an identical sequence by advancing the copy.

For the general case:

```
template<class InIter, class Size, class OutIter>
void copy_n(InIter begin, InIter end, Size n, OutIter dest) {
  for (; begin != end && n > 0; ++begin, --n) {
    *dest++ = *begin;
  }
}

//...
std::string ReadPartial(std::istream& file, int size) {
  std::string result;
  copy_n(istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
         size, back_inserter(result));
  return result;
}
```

However, in this case, you would be better off resizing the string, using istream::read directly into &result[0], and finally checking that you read the desired number of characters.

Comment: But is there a way to do something similar using iterators, or for that matter to get a forward iterator from an ifstream?

Comment: @Allen_SM: Sure you can use iterators, I already included copy_n.  You could write an iterator type for istreams which is a Forward Iterator (since istreams have a seekg method), but there's no need.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard algorithm that can help you here, but you can use this one:

```
template< class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
OutputIterator copy_n(InputIterator from,
                      size_t n,
                      OutputIterator to)
{
    while (n)
    {
        *to = *from;
        ++from;
        ++to;
        --n;
    }
    return to;
}
```

This can be used with `ReadPartial` like this:

```
std::string ReadPartial( std::ifstream& _file, int _size )
{
    std::istreambuf_iterator<char> first( _file );
    std::string result;

    copy_n(first, _size, std::back_inserter(result));
    return result; 
}
```