# Setting an Arbitrary End istream_iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, range, bounds, istream-iterator

Is it possible for me to set an ending `istream_iterator` other than the default constructed one?

One use case would be initializing a `vector<int>` with the first 13 elements from an `istream_iterator<int>`: `vector<int>{ istream_iterator<int>(cin), x)` where `x` is an iterator that is exactly 13 elements away from `istream_iterator<int>(cin)`.

Comment: Highly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086701/reading-a-partial-file-stream-into-a-string-using-iterators

Comment: @NathanOliver It's crazy but I didn't even know that an `istreambuf_iterator` existed till that link made me look it up. The problem does seem to be the same though. This is do able with forward_iterators but not with just iterators.

Comment: Well the problem is it is an input iterator which means when advanced it is read and can never go back.  [Bart's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4086867/4342498) Is how I would do this.